# NavLink: CSS animation on hover and active

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to style a `nav-bar` with some CSS to add some animations to the NavLinks. So I'm trying to accomplish that on hover the text will be underlined from right to left and when a NavLink is active I want it to be underlined.

With my solution I get almost the behaviour I want except that when a NavLink is active the hover animation and the active underline don't overlay each other. The two underlines form two separate underlines below the text.

[Picture of current NavLink with hover and active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lw7GJ.png)

Here is the code:

```
{navItems.map((item) => (
    <div className="example">
        <NavLink
            key={item.title.toLowerCase()}
            className="hover hover-1"
            activeClassName="active"
            to={item.link}
            exact={item.exact}
        >
            {item.title}
        </NavLink>
    </div>
))}
```

And here is the CSS:

```
@import "./../global";

$animate: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
$darkBlue: darkBlue;

.example {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: bottom;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  .hover {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    transition: $animate;
    position: relative;
    &:before,
    &:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
      width: 0px;
      height: 4px;
      margin: 5px 0 0;
      transition: $animate;
      transition-duration: 0.5s;
      opacity: 0;
      background-color: $darkBlue;
    }

    &.hover-1 {
      &:before,
      &:after {
        left: 0;
      }
    }
  }
  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    .hover {
      &:before,
      &:after {
        width: 100%;
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
  }
  .active {
      border-bottom: 4px solid $darkBlue;
  }
}
```

I would very much appreciate some help with this issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement by apply **not** in css like below.

```
.example {
 // remaining properties 

 // EVERYTHING IS SAME BUT JUST ADDED not
.hover:not(.active) {

text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
transition: $animate;
position: relative;
&:before,
&:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 4px;
  margin: 5px 0 0;
  transition: $animate;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: $darkBlue;
}

&.hover-1 {
  &:before,
  &:after {
    left: 0;
  }
 }
}
 // remaining properties
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works better now, but I get this weird behaviour that depending on which NavLink that is active when refreshing the page it works or doesn't work. So the current status is when one of the NavLinks that are not the start page is active when refreshing the page it works, but as soon as I click on the "Start"-NavLink the functionality breaks and goes back to as it was before I implemented (.hover:not(.active))

I think there is a something wrong with the paths and the NavLink prop, exact.

Comment: could you please provide any stackblitz or something?? But for me when I refresh page it is working fine.

Comment: It's working for me as well when I use the core functionality at Stackblitz. So I'm trying to replicate the problem.

As I wrote before, I think there is some problem with the JS code and not the CSS.

I'll keep you updated and thank you for the help

Comment: The problem was that one page had css code which was in conflict with the css in the nav-bar.